# Creating a jQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, select

Curious how I might create a jQuery selector to grab the revenue number out of this code.   Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
  'id': '12457',
  'revenue': '10.75',
  'tax': '0.76',
  'shipping': '0.00'
});
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery works on HTML elements, but that's a function that operates on a JavaScript object. Please clarify.

Comment: A jQuery selector searched the html DOM for the specified elements. You cannot select a parameter from a JS-function.

Comment: That was my understanding as well epmiric.   I'm still a bit of a novice with JS and thought I might be missing some way to grab the data from what was available in the code.

Think I'll just have to push back on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the the array with revenue as an argument for the function so presumably you have access to it outside of the function?  In this case I would define it like the following :

```
var info = {
  id: '12457',
  revenue: '10.75',
  tax: '0.76',
  shipping: '0.00'
};
```

And then access it simply like this :

```
var revenue = info.revenue;
```

Keep in mind this is all basic JavaScript.  If the information is in JSON format you will want to use JSON.parse() to create the JavaScript opject as JSON is typically passed as a string and converted on both ends to objects in the respective languages.

The way you have it written however is not a standard way of writing key-value pairs in JavaScript nor JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the response Luke.   Unfortunately, I have zero control over how the current code is written.   Personally, I'm having to try and pull revenue data through a tag management system so I'm pretty limited.  

Looking at the source code for the page there is no variable for revenue.   I'm wondering if this info is being saved via a tag management system, and this is why I can't find any other revenue objects in the source.

As this isn't written as standard should I just resign to saying this is not possible unless the client can pass through the info as a standard dataLayer?

Comment: Sadly Ethan I think you're stuck.  Now I say this with relatively moderate experience with JS and jquery but if you can find a way to the information as is passed into the ga() function then you may be able to access it from inside there?  If you can see where the information is going once it is passed through the function, you may be able to grab it from inside if that makes sense?

Comment: Did some more digging and the array is actually javascript after all - my bad.  Do you have the ability to write code within the ga() function?  if so, you can use the arguments.length to access them similar to an array and this will tell you how many arguments the function has as a test.  If that works, your "info" parameter would be arguments[2] and I would imagine accessing the revenue key would be as simple as arguments[2].revenue?  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks Luke.   I appreciate you digging into this.   I could probably attempt to mess with the code on the page, but that's venturing into territory that we typically try to stay away from.